# Get void output to variable

Tags: java, eclipse

I have 2 .java files in my project and i want in one of them to show (in a textarea for example) the value of an Enumeration located in the other .java file.

This is the code of the first (or main) .java file - **frm1.java**:
(Just showing what i consider the most relevant part of the code, but if necessary, I can put it completely)

```
// Things HERE
    ListNets interfaceLoader = new ListNets();
    txtrBlabla.setText(names);
```

Where the `txtrBlabla` is the name given for the JTextArea and `ListNets` the name for the second .java file.

And here the second .java file's content - **ListNets.java**:

```
public class ListNets {


    public static void main(String args[]) throws SocketException {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nets = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        for (NetworkInterface netint : Collections.list(nets))
            displayInterfaceInformation(netint);
    }

    public static void displayInterfaceInformation(NetworkInterface netint) throws SocketException {
        out.printf("Display name: %s\n", netint.getDisplayName());
        out.printf("Name: %s\n", netint.getName());
        Enumeration<InetAddress> inetAddresses = netint.getInetAddresses();
     String names = inetAddresses.toString(); //<-- This line is the only thing not "copy-pasted"
     } 
}
```

As you can see, the second code is just a copy&paste.
I've tried loads of ways to get the enumeration's result into a variable and then trying to set it into the textarea using the `txtrBlabla.setText(names);` line, but always get the error message:

> names cannot be resolved into a variable

In the main java file.
I had also seen that's something related to "voids" but no results trying it.
I've also tried changing the variable but neither i get it working.

**Note:**
I'm an starter in JAVA but i really want to understand why this doesn't work.
Sorry for the spelling and thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Also tried putting everything in the same .java file as follows:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws SocketException {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nets = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        for (NetworkInterface netint : Collections.list(nets))
            displayInterfaceInformation(netint);
    }

    static void displayInterfaceInformation(NetworkInterface netint) throws SocketException {
        out.printf("Display name: %s\n", netint.getDisplayName());
        out.printf("Name: %s\n", netint.getName());
        Enumeration<InetAddress> inetAddresses = netint.getInetAddresses();
     String names = inetAddresses.toString();
     }

        txtrBlabla.setText(displayInterfaceInformation.names);
```

Comment: Really, if you're new to programming, starting with UI design isn't a great idea. You should focus on the basics first, like variable scoping.

Comment: `names` is a local variable in your `displayInterfaceInformation` method and is not visible in  the frm1 class

Comment: @Pieter And how can i make it visible? Note: i've also tried putting everything in the same .java file. Gonna edit so you can see.

Comment: @LuisM. This is explained in detail [here](https://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this line is not needed:

```
String names = inetAddresses.toString();
```

Rather I would convert the enumeration of InetAddress objects to a string and then return it for later usage. Something along the lines:

```
public static String getNetworkInformation(NetworkInterface netint) throws SocketException {
    Enumeration<InetAddress> inetAddresses = netint.getInetAddresses();
    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",");
    while(inetAddresses.hasMoreElements()) {
        InetAddress inetAddress = inetAddresses.nextElement();
        joiner.add(inetAddress.toString());
    }
    return joiner.toString();
}
```

By the way: trying to convert a `java.util.Enumeration` to string by calling `toString()` does not produce any meaningful string in Java.

You could try out this code [here in JDoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/a/gFS). This source code in this Doodle prints out the output to the console, but in your case you just need to output it to the UI.

Comment: Do you mean making that change in the second java file; or in the first one and then using txtrBlabla.setText(joiner); or similar one? Thx

Comment: @LuisM. The change I propose should be done in `ListNets.java`. You will need then some extra code to loop through all network interfaces and join the output of the method `getNetworkInformation(NetworkInterface netint)`. This code is on the Doodle I referred to in the answer above. You can just run the Doodle and see what the code does.

Comment: Ok thanks, but what keeps happening is that i can't show the result in the textarea, any ideas about that?

Comment: @LuisM. check another Doodle which shows you how to print out all network interfaces in a JTextArea: https://www.jdoodle.com/a/gGf

Comment: Ok thanks to everyone and @gil.fernandes, everything solved.

Answer (score 0):

*Variable scope is your problem here.*

**Take a look at this:**

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm

The scope of a variable is the part of the program over which the variable name can be referenced. (from Ivor Horton's Beginning Java 2, JDK 5 Edition by Ivor Horton)

You cannot refer to a variable before its declaration.

**You can declare variables in several different places:**

- In a class body as class fields. Variables declared here are referred to as class-level variables.
- As parameters of a method or constructor.
- In a method's body or a constructor's body.
- Within a statement block, such as inside a while or for block.

Go to the link fo learn more about *Variable Scope*.